# Conjecture: there is only one configuration of $d$ lines in $n$ dimensional space where any pair have same angle and $d$ is the max possible.

Tags: geometry, conjectures, solid-geometry

The sequence here: http://oeis.org/A002853 tells us the maximum number of lines that can be placed in $d$ dimensional space in a way that any pair of lines has the same angle as any other pair and all of them pass through the origin. In general, there can be multiple configurations with $n$ lines that satisfy this property. For example, when $d=3$ and we want to place $3$ lines, we can have the coordinate system ($x$, $y$ and $z$ axes) or three lines at $3 \pi/2$ radians restricted to a plane. So, there are at least two such configurations.

I conjecture that when we have the maximum possible number of lines, there will be only one configuration possible. Is it possible to prove this conjecture or refute with counter-example?

---

Related:

1. [Number of configurations of lines in $d$ dimensional space where any pair of them have the same angle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217709/number-of-configurations-of-lines-in-d-dimensional-space-where-any-pair-of-the)
2. [How to draw six lines in 3-d space such that angle between any pair of them is the same.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217177/how-to-draw-six-lines-in-3-d-space-such-that-angle-between-any-pair-of-them-is-t)

Comment: As A002853[4]=A002853[3], your conjecture feels a bit bold. Are all maximal configurations in 4-space actually confined to some hyperplane?

Comment: Good point. Maybe there is a platonic solid in 4-d that could be used to easily refute the conjecture?

Comment: In the body of your Question you seem to have added the requirement that the lines pass through the origin, although any single point of intersection would amount to the same configuration.